# How does IKEv2 work on Android without raw sockets

Tags: android, ipsec, strongswan

I was exploring the `IKEv2` [StrongSwan](https://github.com/strongswan/strongswan) client implementation for Android. What I fail to understand is that `Android` and `Java` do not support *raw sockets*, whilst the `IKEv2 / IPSec` works below `Transport` layer, which seems counter-intuitive. How exactly does the communication happen after the `CHILD_SA` aka `IPSec SA` is established?

**References:**

1. The official documentation for [IKE Charon keying daemon](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Charon) does mention the use of `socket` in the architecture diagram, but I was unable to find any further reference to it.
2. I'm aware of the fact that StrongSwan's Android client uses a user-space implementation of `libipsec`, but again how does `libipsec` communicate without raw sockets?

Any help to fill the gap in my understanding is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client only supports **UDP-encapsulated ESP**. These packets are sent/received over the same UDP sockets that are already used for IKEv2. This limitation is mentioned on the [app's wiki](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/AndroidVPNClient#Known-LimitationsIssues) page.